# How to call a class method of a composer package from PHP CLI?

Tags: php, class, methods, composer-php, command-line-interface

I tried to get it with the following command :

```
php -r 'require("./vendor/autoload.php");packagename\ClassName::myStaticMethod();'
```

but got :

*Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in Command line code on line 1*

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure it is exact command you have run? It should work fine.

Comment: yes it is... php -r 'require("./vendor/autoload.php");' does the same. Something  wrong with autoload.php probably

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Finally it was a quote issue. Being on windows, you need to start the cli command with double quotes and not single. php -r "require('./vendor/autoload.php');packagename\ClassName::myStaticMethod();"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**With your package packagist.org/packages/thipages/jsbuild**

`php -r "require './vendor/autoload.php';thipages\jsbuild\JSBuild::writeBuildModel();"` is working on windows, switching " and '.

Comment: Hi, first thank you. However I would like to use composer autoload. May be I cant.

Comment: Welcome, I tested with a symfony package, it works too. I updated my answer too.

Comment: What are your package, class and method exactly?

Comment: thanks, my package is here : https://packagist.org/packages/thipages/jsbuild and I would like to execute JSBuild::writeBuildModel() after having installed this package with composer : composer require thipages/jsbuild

Comment: Updated my answer, it's ok too

Comment: I cant reproduce it, got  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''namespace' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting end of file in Command line code on line 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229619/discussion-between-tit-and-monnomcjo).

Comment: php -r "require './vendor/autoload.php';thipages\jsbuild\JSBuild::writeBuildModel();" is working on windows, switching " and ' !!! I accept your response when you update it. Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome, answer updated